# Socket.io-client not connecting

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, socket.io

I'm trying to use socket.io-client to listen to the backend of the application I'm working on, but I'm not having success.
In the browser's network it shows that it connected, giving status 200, but when I try to send something and listen, I can't.

In this socket I need to pass the handshake: /socket.io/v1/
I also need to inform the namespace, which is /chat.

Here is how I am setting up my socket.

```
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = socketIOClient(`${process.env.OPSSCRIPT_TICKET_CHAT_SOCKET_URL}`, {
    path: '/socket.io/v1/',
    query: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        ticket_id: tabs[activeTabId].ticketId,
    },
});
```

And here I am listening to him in my chat area

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('msg', (data: unknown) => {
        console.log('DATA: ', data)
    });
}, [activeTabId, socket, tabs, ticketId]);
```

I need help, because I already looked in the documentation and didn't find anything related.
It's important that I pass the /chat namespace, as that's how back is expecting to receive.